# In windows 7, how do I disable "Ease of Access" pop ups on the logon screen as I am typing my password?

Tags: windows-7, login, accessibility

So the question is pretty much in the title.  Things to note:

- 'Use On-Screen Keyboard' is un-checked
- I have disabled Ease of Access by [replacing utilman.exe](http://www.nicholasoverstreet.com/2009/08/vista-and-7-easily-disable-ease-of-access/)

But my problem now is that when I'm typing my password, It'll stop all together on the 'u' or the 'p' character and I have to click on the ease of access button then move focus back to the password to continue.  Yes, one obvious solution is to not use a password that has 'u' or 'p' in it (which I've done), but that's obviously not a completely satisfying answer.

Thanks!

I feel a tumbleweed badge...

Comment: Sorry for my answer.. did not read. Try WIN-T when typping your password.

Comment: How did this start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that p causes different display modes to come up - this means Windows key might be pressed/sticked (since Windows Key + P is the default shortcut to cycle through projector/display).

You can try to disable the Windows key + key shortcuts for a while to see if you still have this problem. 
[Is there any way to disable certain keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/129191/is-there-any-way-to-disable-certain-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-7/129215#129215)

Comment: I had that problem, somehow pressed the windows key and I could type all of my password except the "p". Thanks!

Comment: Same problem, but with Shift+B. WinKey+P solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to log into a server using RDP and needed to use the on-screen keyboard *and* click the Windows key twice before I could enter a 'u' character. The first click turned the key on, then the second reverted it back to off, and then the 'u' key worked as expected.

I am working with a US laptop in Geneva with a European external keyboard at the moment, so I don't pretend to know if that's contributing to this issue. I also experienced the issue where some keys would suddenly stop working. For example, sometimes I was unable to enter 't' or 'h' characters in the To/CC/Subject lines of an Outlook email. In those cases I needed to restart Outlook before they started working again. Strange stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, ok! I got this now:

Download this here:
http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Ease-of-Access-disabler-Download-71010.html

And try this:

**Disable Ease of Access Button**

> Unfortunately, we can’t remove the button, but we can make it disabled so nobody can actually use it. Download and unzip the software, and then right-click on the setup file and choose Run as Administrator.
>
> Choosing to run it as administrator is such an important step that the software will remind you regardless.
>
> You’ll finally get to the screen where you can click the Disable button to make the button not work anymore. If you wanted to re-enable it, just run the setup again and click the Enable button.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-ease-of-access-button-on-vista-logon-screen/

Comment: I've done this already (it's the "I have disabled Ease of Access by replacing utilman.exe" step).  The main problem is that a slew of characters (u,p,t) dont work or cause other things to happen when I type my password.  For example p causes different display modes to come up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have accidentally turned on the 'Sticky Keys' feature of Windows 7. Press both <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys simultaneously to turn it off, then lock the screen and try to log on again.