# Is there any way to disable certain keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, projector

There is something going on with my Windows 7 machine where attempting to unlock the workstation the <kbd>Win</kbd> key is "stuck" on (not quite sure what is causing this).

What this causes is that when I am entering my password, which contains a "p", Windows thinks I am pressing <kbd>Win + p</kbd> as if I want to change my display settings to enable a projector. This is highly annoying when attempting to unlock my workstation!

The workaround I've found to "unstick" the <kbd>Win</kbd> key is to cycle through the projector/display settings once, land back on the original value, and then resume entering my password as normal.

But is there any way to completely disable the shortcut for <kbd>Win + p</kbd> ? In all likelihood I will never hook up a projector to this machine, or on the once-in-a-lifetime chance that I do, I am more than happy with having to go into the Display Settings myself.

Answer (score 17):

One more variant is [described at WindowsSecrets.COM](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/153042-Disable-some-hotkeys-in-Win-7-Home-Premium?s=b84334a448d183c577680125faacc2f9&p=897852&viewfull=1#post897852), and includes a registry patch:

- Setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NoWinKeys` to 1 disables *all* Win+x key combinations at once <sup>(which is not what the OP wants, but I just mention it for completeness)</sup>
- Navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\`, create/edit `DisabledHotkeys` as "Expandable String Value", and add the keys you do not want to be triggered along with the "Win" key (e.g. adding `12P` would disable Win+1, Win+2, and Win+P)

According to the post, those changes would require a restart (a logoff/logon should be enough for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` changes) for the registry to be re-read.

Side-note: I'm not sure whether other apps could re-use hotkeys disabled this way, so take into consideration that this might not be the case.

Other questions here you might wish to lookup:

- [Disable (unbind) default Win+Arrows hotkeys to make them usable in other applications](https://superuser.com/q/459765/143340)
- [How can Win+P be disabled in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/259802/143340)

**Update:** Just found [a post at MSFN](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140220-disable-winspace-hotkey/) explaining how to re-assign those hotkeys to other applications. They used [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) to accomplish that. This app can be used to disable or re-assign hotkeys, and thus probably gives the most flexible solution. If I understood correctly, you could disable the `P` key by simply putting `#p::return` into its config.

Comment: FWIW, this just stopped working for me in the latest Windows 10 update.

Comment: Confirmed to work in Windows 7. Upvoted. The DisabledHotkeys method saved me from activating the windows/openning applications when accidentally pressing Windows+3 instead of AltGr+3 to get the # symbol (Spanish keyboard layout)

Comment: The registry Setting did not work for me in Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19042.985). The autohotkey method worked though. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled "Sticky Keys" by accident and you've got the <kbd>Win</kbd> key in it's "on" state?

If you press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key before entering your password does the problem occur?

[Here's a page](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/2527) that tells you how to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable the Windows Key shortcuts (doesn't disable the Windows Key completely, only the Windows Key + key keyboard shortcuts)

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html

Comment: I'm curious if there is anyway to just disable an individual shortcut

Comment: From what I have seen, no, you can only either disable all Win-key shortcuts or disable them all. That was a very irritating aspect of XP and Microsoft does not seem to have learned at all since then. :| It is (mostly) possible to just disable them all and reproduce certain ones manually. For example, I have managed to use a hotkey program to (re)map Win+D to show the desktop and Win+R to show the Run dialog, but how the heck to you recreate Win+Tab for cycling windows? (Hopefully that last one is not affected by "NoWinKeys".)

Comment: @Synetech (`:-)`), nope Win+Tab is disabled with `NoWinKeys`, however Win+P **is not**. `:-|`

Comment: @mattb See the top upvoted answer, if after all this time you're still struggling with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [HotKeyz](http://hotkeyz.en.softonic.com/) from Skynergy.  You can download it from a variety of freeware download mirrors, such as:  http://hotkeyz.en.softonic.com/

It's free and a fantastic, easy to use tool for remapping/customizing windows hotkeyz.  I don't think the developer updates it anymore, as ver 2.8.3 is the latest and dated 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation with the right-arrow key. Hence, I have to disable that. And also I reassigned the Right_Control key for that.

I have done that through a small freeware named [**SharpKeys** from *RandyRants.com*](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys). I am also attaching my snapshot.

I had to map:

1. the **Right_Arrow_key** to **Disabled(Null)**
2. then the **Right_Control_key** to **Right_Arrow_key**

you only need to do the **First** for your WIN key.

[image]