# Customize Virtual Keyboard for kiosk

Tags: windows-7, windows

how can I disable certain keys on the Windows7 onscreen keyboard?

I managed to disable some keys on the physical keyboard but they are still click able on the  onscreen keyboard.

How to disable special keys like : Win key, ctrl key,...

Comment: does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/352758/how-do-you-disable-hotkeys-in-internet-explorer-9/

Comment: Thanks, can i use this for virtual keyboard?