# Win 8 how to open "Project to a connected screen" without using Win P

Tags: windows-8, projector

how can I disable Win P as "Project to a connected screen".

That means, how can I access to "Project" (Project to a connected screen) without using Win P

I would like to use Win P for another purpose

The best would be get directly to "Duplicate screen" which is the option I usually use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Win+P be disabled in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/259802/how-can-winp-be-disabled-in-windows-7).  While the question is asking how to disable it on `Windows 7` the solution works for `Windows 8.0` also.

Comment: @Ramhound I read that answer, but it is a different issue. It's true I don't want WinP as projector but in orther to have WinP for another purpose I need to be sure that I can access to what WinP brings me down by using another script in AHK. So my question remains: how can access to "Duplicate screen" without using its current WinP

Comment: What?  Please clarify your statement.

Comment: Which is the way to open the right bar entitled "Project" without using WinP? (the best would be that it goes directly to the second option of that  menu, ie, "Duplicate". thanks!