# How to disable Alt+Esc shortcut on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying for a week to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut in Windows 8, but I can't use any running tool like AutoHotKey.

Already searched in Regedit, Gpedit, Control Panel, and a lot of googling. However, I just found tutorials about disabling <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcuts or changing scancodes.

So, someone know how to disable **only** the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> hotkey?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/129191/is-there-any-way-to-disable-certain-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-7

Comment: Does this answer help? http://superuser.com/a/523832/62271

Comment: Unfortunately no, SharpKeys only change one scancode for another, I need to set a key combination (Alt+Esc) to 'null'

Comment: Windows doesn't provide a built-in way to turn off arbitrary hotkeys, and you can't use third-party tools. That pretty much rules out any possible solutions, short of manually patching the executable bits that handles Alt+Esc. Why do you need to disable it?

Comment: I can use third-party tools, but only if they write to a registry or something and can be closed/uninstalled from Windows. In a specific game I use Alt > Click > Esc > Alt > ... Doing this fast cause Alt+Esc and the game minimize, also any KeyBinding-OnTheFly is recognized as a cheat and shutdown the game-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only partial solution which I can achieve, its to lock the application into full screen mode, and close all other applications which have a window context to be switched, in this way the shortcut don't get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If those suggestions don't work you could try finding the process that allows Alt-Tab to work (it's not explorer.exe) and kill that process (if safe) while your lock is in place.